# Why use a sleep method after invoking the subscribe in Python ActiveMQ listener with STOMP

Tags: python-3.x, activemq-classic, stomp

I am studying the ActiveMQ client code (**consumer**) written in Python. It uses the STOMP protocol. I am unable to understand why we are invoking a `sleep` and `disconnect` methods after subscribing to the destination queue. Could someone help me to understand the real process behind below python listener code.

Questions:

1. Why we are invoking a `sleep` and `disconnect` methods after invoking `subscribing` to the destination queue?
2. When does it call **on_message()** method?

   ```
   import stomp
   import time

   class SampleListener(object):
     def on_message(self, headers, msg):
       print(msg)

   conn = stomp.Connection([('localhost',61613)]) 
   conn.set_listener('SampleListener', SampleListener()) 
   conn.start() 
   conn.connect() 
   conn.subscribe(destination='queue_name', id=1, ack='auto')
   time.sleep(10) # secs 
   conn.disconnect()
   ```

Comment: The sleep doesn't have anything to do with `ActiveMQ` or `stomp` itself. It's merely there so that the sample program doesn't immediately disconnect `x` microseconds after you've created the subscription. Once execution of the program is complete, they demonstrate disconnecting to release the underlying connection.

Comment: Thanks @chucksmash With subscribe method it is sending a packed frame to the server. But what happens after that? When does that on_message() method get executed? Does it receive multiple messages from queue, or just one at a time?

Comment: Sorry for delay...that description was really helpful...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to note here is that the `SampleListener` instance set on `conn` when invoking `set_listener` will be invoked **asynchronously** when a message arrives on the queue. In other words, the client won't simply wait/block until a message arrives. Therefore, the `sleep` needs to be invoked in order to keep the consumer alive for a bit waiting for a message. If a message arrives during this `10` second window then the `SampleListener` will receive it and print the message (i.e. using `print(msg)`). If a message doesn't arrive on the queue then the `SampleListener` won't be invoked and the application will simply terminate.

The `disconnect` at the end is just good resource management. In general it's bad practice to terminate an application without cleaning up the resources (e.g. connections) it created. If `disconnect` is *not* invoked and the application terminates then the broker will be forced to eventually close the connection itself and clean up any server-side resources.

If `on_message` takes more than 10 seconds (i.e. the duration of `sleep`) I'm not sure what will happen. I recommend you try it and see.

Comment: Thanks @Justin for the explanation. That helps a lot. But, could you please explain the behavior if we don’t have a disconnect method invoked after sleep. We have only 10sec sleep. Will the client listen only for 10 seconds and end? And if a message is received within 10 seconds, but the on_message process takes more than 10 sec, does the disconnect method wait till the process complete?